# Total calculating SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

In Report Builder (SSRS) I need to calculate total of "Mix ACT vs BGT" by Brand as sum of values "Mix ACT vs BGT" by SKU. SKU is a child group of Brand group.
"Mix ACT vs BGT" by SKU formula looks like:

```
[>     =iif((Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Volume", Fields!P_L_Budget.Value, 0)))=0, ((Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value =
> "Volume", Fields!P_L_ACT.Value, 0))-Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value =
> "Volume",  Fields!P_L_Budget.Value, 0)))*(
> iif((Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Gross Revenue", 
> Fields!P_L_ACT.Value, 0))/Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Volume",
> Fields!P_L_ACT.Value, 0)))=0, 0, (Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value =
> "Gross Revenue", Fields!P_L_ACT.Value,
> 0))/Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Volume", Fields!P_L_ACT.Value,
> 0))))-VariablesPL_GROSS_REVENUE_HL_BGT.Value))),
> ((Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Volume",  Fields!P_L_ACT.Value,
> 0))-Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Volume", 
> Fields!P_L_Budget.Value, 0)))*( iif((Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value =
> "Gross Revenue",  Fields!P_L_Budget.Value,
> 0))/Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Volume", 
> Fields!P_L_Budget.Value, 0)))=0, 0, (Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value =
> "Gross Revenue",  Fields!P_L_Budget.Value,
> 0))/Sum(iif(Fields!PL_Natural.Value = "Volume",
> Fields!P_L_Budget.Value,
> 0))))-(Variables!PL_GROSS_REVENUE_HL_BGT.Value))))][1]
```

I can't use the same formula for brand, it returns incorrect result, so I need to get a sum of values. Which method i should use for this purpose? I tried tu use ReportItems collections, but it doesn't work with aggregation. So please help. Thank you in advance!

Sorry, i can't attach a pic because of my low reputation :(

Comment: Your expression is very hard to read - too much nesting. I think you can write it to be more simple

Comment: This expression works fine for me, i have a question about total value and this is for information mostly.

Comment: Consider doing this in your source proc. Will be easier. If grouping is a problem just takr FIRST() in the report.

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering is there any posibility do this calculations in the tablix. For example, calculated field doesn't allow work with variables, but the task implies the presence of it. So i can't doing this in source, as I see.